# gradle provided still includes in jar files

Tags: java, gradle, apache-storm

I want to preface this with I am still new to gradle and hopefully someone can clarify any misconceptions I might have. 
I have a gradle build script that compiles my project and builds into a RPM. In one of my subprojects I have the following snippet:

```
dependencies {
    provided libraries.stormCore
}
```

where `libraries.stormCore` is just a map literal with the `stormCore` pointing to the maven dependency object `'org.apache.storm:storm-core:0.10.0'`

However, once my project compiles I am seeing in my jar `defaults.yaml` which comes from the `stormCore` library and I was under the impression `provided` would not add any of the dependencies into the jar. This is causing storm to start erroring with `multiple defaults.yaml found`. `provided` comes from the `nebula-provided-base` package.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Gradle Java plugin doesn't have a 'provided' configuration. Did you define it yourself or is it added by a plugin?

Comment: @WilcoGreven sorry, I forgot to add that, its the nebula-provided-base plugin. I'll edit the original post as well